# Center SKLabelNode in SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode with an attached image

```
menu_bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "menu_bg")
```

Additionally I want a SKLabelNode to be added as a child of menu_bg and this SKLabelNode should be centered horizontally and vertically wihtin the menu_bg node.
To do so, I added the menu_bg to the scene

```
self.addChild(menu_bg)
```

And I create a new SKLabelNode and add it to the menu_bg and try to place it centered

```
self.menu_bg.addChild(menuTitleLabel!)
self.menuTitleLabel!.position = CGPoint(x: menu_bg.frame.width/2, y: menu_bg.frame.height/2)
```

But the Label is not displayed centered.
Any ideas what I am missing?

I also tried to add

```
self.menuTitleLabel!.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center
```

but with no effect,...

any ideas?

Comment: Which way is it shifted?  What if the position was set to 0, 0 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting the position, you will need to account for the menuTitleLabel height and width as well.

```
self.menuTitleLabel!.position = CGPoint(x: menu_bg.frame.width/2 - (menuTitleLabel.frame.width/2), y: menu_bg.frame.height/2 -(menuTitleLabel.frame.height/2))
```

This should center it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the hint of @Glideman and when I set the label to 0,0 they were already centered, since the anchor of a SpriteNode is always in it´s center - as I learned now ;-)
Thank you for your help and approach to find a solution :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help!